# Keyboard Shortcut for Grouping Objects in Word 2013?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

Please tell me how I can create a shortcut for grouping objects?  If there is already one, I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit more cumbersome than a shortcut, but I just memorized the context menu keyboard commands for group, ungroup, and regroup.

- Right-click, G, G for group
- Right-click, G, U for ungroup
- Right-click, G, O for regroup

If your keyboard has the context menu key, you can use it instead of right-clicking:

[image: context key]

If not, `Shift-F10` will also work.

Answer (score 1):

This article describes how to create custom shortcuts in Word 2013 http://www.groovypost.com/howto/customize-office-2013-keyboard-shortcuts/

EDIT:
So I went looking for the group shortcut. If you go to "File >> Options >> Customize Ribbon" and click "Customize" next to "Keyboard Shortcuts", you will get a menu for all possible options you can assign keyboard shortcuts to. Under the category "All Commands", you will find the command "DrawGroup". (Note that when I assign a keyboard shortcut to this command, I can't get it to work, but I guess it might depend on what objects you are trying to group, so you could try to test it out or go through the list and see if I missed some other grouping command.)

I also went into PowerPoint to check which command Ctrl + G was assigned to, but as a rather weird limitation, it is not possible to customize the keyboard shortcuts in PowerPoint.

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon. Also that's the general way to go about it but can you provide more details, such as is it even possible to assign a shortcut for grouping objects, and if so which command should be selected?

Comment: Wasn't CTRL+G used to be the built-in shortcut for grouping objects? I just tried in Word 2010 but it's not working now.

Comment: Ok, sry about that, i updated my answer to be more detaield. Ctrl + G only works in poweropint i believe.